# Is there a name for this technique?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, notation, terminology

I have to assume this is fairly common, but I'd like to know if there is a term for this technique, and what branch of mathematics it is a part of. *(For reference, I have no formal training, but fell into a set of problems I need to solve, and I'm trying to understand the landscape.)*

Forgive me if I'm expressing this poorly, and feel free to correct my notation and terminology:

For a set of numbers $1,2,3,4,$ where $0<n<5$

$4 + n = n$

and

$1 - n = 5 - n$

*I understand this is analogous to a 2-bit register, and there's a problem involving reduction of symmetries in a 2^2 Latin square where this proved quite handy.*

Comment: And could you be thinking about [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)?

Comment: It does look like congruence modulo $4$.

Comment: It indeed looks to be Modular arithmetic. (Gauss's name has been popping up a lot, I'm psyched to finally make the connection. Plenty of material there for me to study.) Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

To future readers: he was thinking of [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).